# How to search for an existing theorem in Lean?

Tags: lean

When proving things in a theorem prover, I am often using sizable libraries that I don’t know by heart, so it is crucial to be effective in discovering existing theorems.

What are the best approaches here? Both within the IDE (likely less friction, but also likely restricted to theorems from the currently imported modules), but also on the web (to find more stuff)? Is there something like [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20b)%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bb%5D) that allows me to search for concrete types, or something like [Isabelle’s `find_theorem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255473/using-find-theorems-in-isabelle), where I can search for theorems by name, by a pattern expression LHS of simplification rule, and other clever ways?

Comment: So, we need an answer that *at least* covers the `library_search` and `suggest` tactics and at the same time explains their use cases as well as how to use them (`suggest` in particular is difficult to use until you have some experience decoding names in Lean).

Comment: It sometimes works well to enter keywords in the search box at https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib or the one at https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/.

Comment: There is also now https://www.moogle.ai/ which is an AI powered search engine for Lean theorems.

Comment: Right – turn it into an answer! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bothered by the lack of something like `find_theroems` and Hoogle, I have implemented a search engine that has some of its features; [Loogle](https://loogle.lean-lang.org/).

[image: Loogle web interface]

It can search by occurring constants, name substrings or aribtrary patterns, and can be accessed using the [web page](https://loogle.lean-lang.org/), a [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShreyasSrinivas.loogle-lean), is integrated into `lean.nvim` or can be used [locally](https://github.com/nomeata/loogle) via a CLI, a Lean command or (again) a browser interface.

Answer (score 14):

I use three strategies to find existing lemmas: the `exact?` tactic, the `gptf` tactic and guessing the name based on mathlib naming conventions.

## `exact?`

`exact?` is a mathlib tactic, not a Lean tactic. (It was earlier called `library_search`.) It tries to find a single lemma from the library to solve the current goal, also using local hypotheses to fill in arguments. To make the best use of this tactic, make sure that:

- The current context doesn't have many extraneous assumptions. You might want to use the `clear` and the `clear_except` tactic to remove unnecessary assumptions. If you don't do this, `exact?` might timeout.
- You have introduced all necessary variables and hypotheses. If your goal has forall and imply then it's very likely that `library_search` won't be able to find anything.
- The assumptions are in [`simp` normal form](https://leanprover-community.github.io/extras/simp.html#simp-normal-form).
- `exact?` will only succeed if it can close the goal. If you would also like candidate incomplete solutions (i.e. where a library lemma can be applied to the goal, but then that lemma has hypotheses that can not be filled from the local context) then use `apply?` instead.
- There is now a relative of `apply?` for rewriting, called `rw?`, which will try to rewrite the current goal by a single lemma from the library, returning multiple candidates if none close the goal.

## `gptf`

Unfortunately, this tactic is no longer a thing.

> This tactic uses artificial intelligence. It is faster than `library_search`, and sometimes smarter. When you are stuck, sometimes `gptf` can give helpful hints. In addition to finding mathlib lemmas, sometimes `gptf` can suggest tactics and complete proofs.
>
>  Follow the instructions [on GitHub](https://github.com/jesse-michael-han/lean-gptf) to get access to this tactic.

## mathlib naming conventions

Please familiarize yourself with the [naming conventions](https://leanprover-community.github.io/contribute/naming.html). You can often find lemmas by guessing its name and letting autocomplete help you.

Comment: I've not been able to use `gptf` for a while in the latest versions - do you know how to make it work?

Comment: Also, it may be worth mentioning `suggest` and the `using ...` variants of both of these

Comment: How does `library_search` relate to `suggest`? I often find that the latter finds a small `exact …` proof, while the former doesn’t produce anything.

Comment: I generally find that `library_search` works better if I restate the desired lemma on its own and use the tactic there, rather than using it in the midst of a complex proof.

Comment: Which one of this is the closest to the `Search` command in Coq?

Answer (score 1):

There's moogle.ai. It does semantic search over mathlib